# Variables in Python MySQL connector not working when in function

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have made a function to tidy up the SQL calls I will be doing in my program.
Normally this will work

```
mycursor = mydbr.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT song FROM charts WHERE artist=%s",(artist,))
x = mycursor.fetchone()
```

My function looks like this

```
import mysql.connector
def SqlQuery(connection, query, forvar1 = None, forvar2 = None):
    sqlobj = connection.cursor()
    if forvar1 is None and forvar2 is None:
        sqlobj.execute(query)
    if forvar1 is not None and forvar2 is None:
        sqlobj.execute(query, forvar1)
    if forvar1 is not None and forvar2 is not None:
        queryvars = (forvar1,forvar2)
        sqlobj.execute(query % queryvars)
    result = sqlobj.fetchone()
    connection.commit
    return result
```

List of queries

```
sql = ["SELECT song FROM charts WHERE artist=%s"]
```

My function call looks like this

```
record = SqlQuery(mydbr, sql[0], artist)
```

But whenever it runs it misses adding the variable at all, I have watched what is being sent through wireshark and that looks like

```
SELECT song FROM charts WHERE artist=%s
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Damn I tried so many variations but this site had the right one

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/

```
sqlobj.execute(query, forvar1)
```

Should have been

```
sqlobj.execute(query, (forvar1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, proper syntax and i described as per below:

```
import mysql.connector
def SqlQuery(connection, query, forvar1 = None, forvar2 = None):
    sqlobj = connection.cursor()
    if forvar1 is None and forvar2 is None:
        sqlobj.execute(query)
    if forvar1 is not None and forvar2 is None:
        sqlobj.execute(query, (forvar1, ) )
    if forvar1 is not None and forvar2 is not None:
        queryvars = (forvar1,forvar2, )
        sqlobj.execute(query, queryvars)
    result = sqlobj.fetchone()
    connection.commit
    return result
```

`Example`:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = %s"
adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )

mycursor.execute(sql, adr)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The purpose was to make it a function so I didn't have to write 5 lines of code everytime I wanted to do a query.